# Relationship between work and energy in an electrostatic system

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential-energy

I am having problems understanding the relationship between the concepts of Work and Energy in a electrostatic system.

As I know, the definition of **Potential Energy** is the ability to **do** work. In a gravitational field, that would be $$\mathrm{PE} = W(\mathrm{after}) = -W(\mathrm{before})$$ where $W(\mathrm{before})$ is the Work done to bring the object from infinity to a certain position in space, and $W(\mathrm{after})$ the contrary, from position to infinity.

Now, in the case of an electrostatic system, it seems that the Potential Energy is the Work **required** to bring the charges together (this is what most websites say, [example](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node56.html)). That would be $$\mathrm{PE} = W(\mathrm{before})$$ Does this mean that $\mathrm{PE} = -W(\mathrm{after})$? That would be for me **minus** the ability to **do** Work.

Am I completely missing the idea of $W(\mathrm{after})$ in a electrostatic system?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Sorry, i was not too clear. By W(before) i mean the work done to bring the object from infinity to a certain position, and by W(after) the contrary, from a position to infinity. That's why i wrote P= W(aft) = -W(bfr)

Comment: @AnubhavGoel minus the Work done to bring the object from infinity to a certain position in space?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel yes that is what i wrote. Look, we know that gravity PE is always negative. That is because the PE at infinity is zero, and the work to bring the object from infinity to a position (W(before)) is positive (since direction of movement and direction of attractive gravity force are the same). So the Work to bring it the other way, towards infinity (W(after)) is negative, which is equal to Potential Energy, the ability to do work (which is after all again, W(after)).

Comment: Who did the work Field or us?

Comment: Potential energy is equal to the
work done by the external agent for
moving a body to its given position
in space from infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that every time we talk about work being done, we must know which *force* that is doing it as well as how the *signs* are defined.

> where $W(begin)$ is the Work done to bring the object from infinity to a certain position in space, and $W(after)$ the contrary, from position to infinity."

What force is doing this work?

That would be some external force pushing them together, which they are resisting (if their signs are equal, which I assume here) giving:

$$PE=W_a=W$$

The electric force between them is repelling and is doing the *same amount* of *negative* work! But since it is the system itself that is doing this work, then we put a minus in front:

$$PE=-W_b=-(-W)=W$$

As a rule of thumb, energy *into* the system is positive. That's why work by external forces is positive, since that could typically bring energy in from the outside. Energy *out of* the system is negative. That's why work done *by* the system is given a minus sign, since that could typically mean work spent from the system on something external. **But** that is very often defined either this or the opposite way in different textbooks.

So it depends

- **first of all** on which force is doing the work, and
- **second if all** on how the sign on work is defined (is work done *on* the system positive or negative).

Often this is merely a matter of words, since if the energy content rose then we know without more math that work was done *on* the system, which in the case of charges means that they are closer together. Then the direction is known and doesn't have to be determined from signs.

Comment: then why is work done by external agent negative when we raise an object by a height H

Comment: @harambe It is not? You apply positive work to the object-earth system to raise the potential energy.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/271031/why-is-the-potential-energy-equal-to-the-negative-integral-of-a-force.The answer by zhutchens1

Comment: I am getting confused at this part...I solved my textbook questions using your analysis and I got right answers but I am getting confused about the whole work done and potential energy scenario??

Comment: When we lift an object by a height H with reference with the ground then Work done by gravity is mgh which is equal to the external force .So which one of them will have negetive sign and why

Comment: @harambe Hmm, I do not fully agree with that answer in the other question, unless I misunderstood it. We always talk about **two forces** in regards to potential energy: one which is doing the external work such as your lifting force - this is the **external force** - and one which is the "go back to normal" force such as gravity (or the spring force in a spring, or the electric repulsion between charges etc) - this is the **conservative force**....

Comment: ... When **the potential energy is increased**, work done by the conservative force is negative and work by the external force positive. Increasing the potential energy is the same as "charging" the system with energy (such as compressing a spring and thus storing energy in it), so we need energy from the outside. Therefore work by the external forces is positive. When **the potential energy is decreased**, work done by the conservative force is positive and that by any external force would be negative...

Comment: ... That also makes sense since you new "spend" the stored potential energy meaning that the energy is given to the outside. The outside takes energy away from this system. Taking energy away corresponds to negative work. Maybe the issue is that these two simultaneous conservative and external forces are not always clearly separated.

Comment: So in short the work done by external force is positive when it increases potential energy and is negative when potential energy is decreased because the work done by external force is spending the enrgy of the system

Comment: Also work done by system is negative when potential energy is increased because the system generally tries to lower the energy of the system by spending the energy the system intially so when energy is decreased the work done by the system is positive because the enrgy is given to outside which is we want the system doe everytime so the work done by it should also be positive as this is what we want and when energy is decreased the system does negative work because it is trying to decrease the energy which is contrary to what we want

Comment: @harambe Something like that, yes (your sentence I pretty looong there but I think I get your meaning)

Comment: But If I take the system to be a book and Earth and raise the book to some height then work done by system will be negative but if I take the system to be book only then also the work done will be negative.In the first case,the system was acting internally but in the second case an external force was acting on the object  but both of them have same sign.....How is that possible

Comment: @Abhinav Why should that not be possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are two equivalent ways of defining the potential at a point.

- The potential at a point is the work done by an external force in
  bring unit positive charge from the zero of potential (often taken as
  infinity) to the point.
- The potential at a point is minus the work done by the electric field
  in bring unit positive charge from the zero of potential (often taken
  as infinity) to the point.